# Python Opencv-python crashes when running

Tags: python, opencv

As the title state python is crashing whenever I try to call `sift.detectAndComputer()`

```
def compare_images():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    target = os.path.join(cwd, 'target.png')
    images_list = os.listdir('images')
    for image in images_list:
        # get my 2 images
        img1 = cv2.imread(os.path.join(cwd, 'images', image))
        img2 = cv2.imread(target)

        # Initiate SIFT detector
        sift = cv2.SIFT()

        # find the key points and descriptors with SIFT
        kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
        kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

        # bf matcher with default params
        bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
        matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

        # apply ratio test
        good = []
        for m, n in matches:
            if m.distance < .75 * n.distance:
                good.append([m])

        img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, flags=2)
        plt.imshow(img3)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    compare_images()
```

When I hit this line `kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)` I get a windows popup that says: "Python has stopped working

A problem cause the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program."

Then in the console output I get this:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Not sure what's going on here and why I am not getting a more descriptive error of failure for this. Any help/fixes?

Comment: pretty sure that should be `sift = cv2.SIFT_create()` and not `sift = cv2.SIFT()`

Comment: You are correct! I was looking at an old guide and that's what they used. My IDE and python itself didn't explicitly say that method was an issue which is kinda confusing me now